# Hydrostatic pressure trapped inside a bottle

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, atmospheric-science

I think I almost understand what is going on here, I just need a discussion

The question is: **Why is hydrostatic pressure trapped inside bottle?**

I have an open bottle and then I put a cap on it. The pressure inside should be the atmospheric 1000hPa. But that is due to weight of the sea of air above the bottle? The contact with the sea of air is lost when the bottle is sealed. Why would the pressure inside remain as 1000hPa?

Comment: And that weight of air above it makes a certain density of gas where you are. Putting a cap on the bottle does not change the density of gas in the now sealed bottle, so the pressure remains.

Comment: Oh! So it all about the density. Great, thanks :)